# What is the cause of an iOS 12 ".cold.1" viewcontroller crash, pertaining to CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a crash in my iOS application that appears to be unique to iOS 12 only. This crash started happening when Xcode 11.3 was released.

The stack trace is as follows

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x20148b0dc __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x201504094 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x2013e3ea8 abort + 140
3  Field Portal                   0x100d9cc74 -[InventoryViewController initializeData].cold.1 + 4305833076
4  Field Portal                   0x100c1227c -[PSICoreDataController saveViewContext] + 73 (PSICoreDataController.m:73)
5  CoreData                       0x2044832b0 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x20132d7d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x2012db008 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1068
8  CoreFoundation                 0x201880b20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
9  CoreFoundation                 0x20187ba58 __CFRunLoopRun + 1924
10 CoreFoundation                 0x20187afb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
11 GraphicsServices               0x203a7c79c GSEventRunModal + 104
12 UIKitCore                      0x22e0dcc38 UIApplicationMain + 212
13 Field Portal                   0x100c1939c main + 14 (main.m:14)
14 libdyld.dylib                  0x20133e8e0 start + 4
```

InventoryViewController is a very specific view controller nested VERY deeply within the application, and is not used by any user of my app (yes, I know this).

It seems like what is happening is when I call a save on my primary viewContext, the iOS runtime is somehow initializing InventoryViewController on its own, triggering this function, which results in a crash.

InitializeData itself merely executes a simple NSFetchRequest against the main CoreData context, and if I access this view through normal means, it will not crash on the impacted hardware/OS.

What I don't understand is WHY is iOS doing this? This view controller is never accessed by users, and it is never called directly by any of my code.

Furthermore, this code has not changed in almost a calendar year, and suddenly started happening only on these new builds, and only on iOS 12.

I've found this issue impossible to debug, and would welcome any insight on methodologies for research and analysis on how I can figure out what the cause of this issue is.

Comment: Maybe you could share some code.

Comment: The offset for that call (4305833076) looks suspiciously close to 2^32.  So I would take a close look to check your code is fully 64bit compliant.